# Extract standard errors from tsls output

Tags: r

I want to extract the standard errors from the output of the *tsls* command in the *sem* R package.

Using some generic code as an example:

```
fit = tsls(Y ~ X, ~Z)
summary(fit)
```

The summary function outputs several things besides the regression estimates (e.g., model formulas, summary of the residuals).

I want an equivalent to *fit$coef* that outputs standard errors.  But that doesn't seem to be an option. All the code used to do the equivalent for *glm* and *lm* output doesn't seem to work here. Is there any way to hack the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes it takes a little bit of digging to find where these values are coming from. The best place to look, if you don't get any clues from `str(fit)`, would be to look at what `summary.tsls` is doing.

With some help from `getAnywhere("summary.tsls")`, we see:

```
getAnywhere("summary.tsls")
# A single object matching ‘summary.tsls’ was found
# It was found in the following places
#   registered S3 method for summary from namespace sem
#   namespace:sem
# with value
# 
# function (object, digits = getOption("digits"), ...) 
# {
# ###
# ### \\\SNIP///
# ###
#     std.errors <- sqrt(diag(object$V))
# ###
# ### \\\SNIP///
# ###
# }
# <bytecode: 0x503c530>
# <environment: namespace:sem>
```

So, to get the value you are looking for, you need to calculate it yourself with:

```
sqrt(diag(fit$V))
```

---

A reproducible example:

```
library(sem)
fit <- tsls(Q ~ P + D, ~ D + F + A, data=Kmenta)
summary(fit)
# 
#  2SLS Estimates
# 
# Model Formula: Q ~ P + D
# 
# Instruments: ~D + F + A
# 
# Residuals:
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
# -3.4300 -1.2430 -0.1895  0.0000  1.5760  2.4920 
# 
#                Estimate  Std. Error  t value   Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept) 94.63330387  7.92083831 11.94738 1.0762e-09 ***
# P           -0.24355654  0.09648429 -2.52431   0.021832 *  
# D            0.31399179  0.04694366  6.68869 3.8109e-06 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 1.9663207 on 17 degrees of freedom

sqrt(diag(fit$V))
# (Intercept)           P           D 
#  7.92083831  0.09648429  0.04694366
```

Comment: +1 Good solution. I can't understand why the results of the function `summary.tsls` are printed and then the function returns `NULL`. What a waste of time...